# Power Bi show data with multiple conditions

Tags: if-statement, filter, powerbi, dax

I am trying to help a public school here, but I have very limited knowledge in Power Bi so I hope your guys could enlight me on this case:

we have a very simple report with a table and a kpi

Kpi counts all students
table shows studants grades

```
Student    Math        Portuguese       History       Science
StD A       6           6                7             8
StD B       6           7                6             7
StD C       8           9                7             8
StD D       6           6                6             6
StD E       6           7                8             8
StD F       8           6                7             7
```

the rule that must be applied to the kpi (count(Students)) and to the table is to show studenst only if:

- at least 2 subjects are equal or under 6
- portuguese is equal or under 6
- math is under 6

all the rest should not be showed in the table or counted in the KPI. In this case I would see/count only students A, B, D,E & F

any help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 1):

To tackle your task try the following:

1. Create a calculated column in your table with the following DAX code:

```
isValid = 
    VAR cond_2_subjects = (('Table'[Math] <= 6 ) + ('Table'[Portuguese] <= 6) + ('Table'[History] <= 6) + ('Table'[Science] <= 6)) >= 2
    VAR cond_portuguese = 'Table'[Portuguese] <= 6
    VAR cond_math = 'Table'[Math] < 6
RETURN
    -- This will check if any of the given conditions is true
    IF(
        cond_2_subjects || cond_portuguese || cond_math,
        TRUE(),
        FALSE()
    )
```

The table should then look like this:

[image: Resulting Table with calculated column]

2. The KPI (measure) can then be written like so:

```
# Students = 
    CALCULATE(
        COUNT('Table'[Student]),
        -- only count Students where conditions are true (calculated column isValid = True)
        'Table'[isValid] = TRUE()
    )
```

The final result should then look like this:

[image: Visuals]

The table on the left has specified `'Table'[isValid] = TRUE()` as filter on visual

[image]